# Excel VBA to read digital signature contents

Tags: excel, vba, cryptography, digital-signature

I am trying to introduce digital signatures in excel for digitally approving internal documents.

What i need to do is to disable the digital signature from being resigned (edited) once signed initially.

The logic I plan to do is run a check in "VBA" to see if the person who digitally signed the document matches the name I initialized in my code.

For example:

```
dim Name as string
Name = "Firstname Lastname"
```

Excel automatically captures the name of the person digitally signing the document based on Windows login.  All I now need is to check if the name captured by excel matches the one who is authorized for approving.

I can write the entire code, only part I need help with is for "VBA to read the content of the digital signature"

Link to test file added:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9419bmzm6ejb9zh/signature%20test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Not sure why someone would rate this negatively, at least the person should write comments that are useful to help me understand the problem with my question.

Comment: It's a bit broad and doesn't contain indications to what you've tried, although I guess in this case getting the right function is the main issue. There seems to be somebody that seems to downvote almost any crypto question; it's hard to say as many questions *are* really horrible, this one seems rather OK though, and has at least an interesting subject. Unfortunately I don't know the answer. PS changed [tag:signature] tag to [tag:digital-signature]; read the description of the tags! Use often used tags such as [tag:cryptography] instead of ones with less followers.

Comment: Thank for so very much for your positive comments. You are right, it is useless for me to do all the vba if the main function cannot be accomplished, it is all dependent on it. hope someone out there can help. Thanks again for the support :)

Comment: @Nadz - did you ever figure this one out?